# Interaction Diagrams - Reinforce Concrete Design

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, reinforced-concrete

I am confused on how to located the c value of an interaction diagram. I am given a unsymmetrical bar placement and there is a result that produces a negative moment meaning the location of the point is at the negative x-axis what does that mean and how can I calculate a value of c without a given Pn that point or Mn can someone briefly explain me the concept of the process of creating interaction diagrams of unsymmetrical bar placements

Comment: A diagram would be useful for those that could help you.